# Is monotonicity redundant in this definition of Tarskian logics?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, formal-proof

Given a logic over a language $L$, which has a consequence relation $\vdash$. This logic is Tarskian if for every $\Gamma \cup \Delta \cup {\alpha} \subseteq L$:

1. If $\alpha \in \Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$
2. If $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$ and for every $\beta \in \Gamma$, it is known that $\Delta \vdash \beta$, then $\Delta \vdash \alpha$
3. Monotonicity: If $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$ and $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$, then $\Delta \vdash \alpha$

This definition is provided in Carnielli and Coniglio's [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-33205-5) on Paraconsistent Logic. It seems to me that the monotonicity property is implied by the prior two.

Here's a proof sketch:

Assume we have $\Gamma, \Delta, \alpha$ such that $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$ and $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$. Assume any $\beta \in \Gamma$. Since $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$, we can show that $\beta \in \Delta$. Then by property 1 we know that $\Delta \vdash \beta$. Thus, by property 2, we get $\Delta \vdash \alpha$.

Is there anything wrong in my proof sketch? Why did the authors specifically add the monotonic property, if it is implied by the other two?

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: Thank you @EmilJeřábek